# Is this function always positive for $a<1$?

Tags: functions, special-functions

I have following function:

$$
f(x)=(x+2)[(a+x)^2Ei(-a-x)\exp(a+x)+a]+x(x+1),
$$

where $0<a<1$ and $x>0$ and $Ei(x)$ is the exponential integral. Is it possible to show that $f(x)$ is always positive? I have plotted this function over various values of $a$ in WA and the plot shows that $f(x)$ is positive. So can we prove it analytically? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. If we can not prove it analytically then is there any other method to prove it.

Comment: Use the definition of the exponential integral and the properties of the exponential function

Comment: @YuriyS Ok. By using them I can show that $f(x)$ is always positive. Do you know that it is always positive?

Comment: You say: "By using them I can show that f(x) is always positive." Then you ask "Do you know that it is always positive?" $$ $$ Doesn't the one follow from the other?

Comment: @YuriyS I meant that I know the procedure. But I am not sure whether the function is always positive or not.

Comment: Please rewrite your formula so it is clear which part is under the exponent and which is not.

Comment: @YuriyS I have corrected it as you mentioned